# updating records from another table with filtering

Tags: mysql

I'm not an expert in MySQL and I'm facing a problem which I don't know how to solve.

I've two tables.

```
Table `players`
id | name | high_score
---|------|-----------
1  | john | -
2  | mary | -
3  | mike | -

Table `scores`
id | id_player | score
---|-----------|------
1  | 1         | 12
2  | 1         | 5
3  | 3         | 8
4  | 2         | 7
5  | 2         | 25
6  | 3         | 18
```

This could sound stupid, but I would like to update the high score record of the first table, based on the maximum value on the second table.

I arrived to this solution, which is incomplete:

```
UPDATE `productos_players` p INNER JOIN `scores` s ON (p.id = s.id_player) SET p.high_score=s.score
```

This is what I've done so far, but I still need to modify the query for `scores` to get the maximum MAX() and limit it to 1 result or something similar, but I don't know how to do it, or even if it is possible.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following `UPDATE` to update the high scores:

```
UPDATE `players` p 
SET p.high_score = (
    SELECT MAX(score) 
    FROM scores 
    WHERE id_player = p.id
);
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7320c3/2/0

---

Another solution would be to use a [`VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html):

```
CREATE VIEW v_players AS
    SELECT players.*, MAX(scores.score) AS 'high_score' 
    FROM players LEFT JOIN scores ON players.id = scores.id_player 
    GROUP BY players.id
```

The advantage of using a `VIEW` is not to update the table after each change of the `scores` table.

---

**How to use the `UPDATE` automatically using a [`TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html):**
The `UPDATE` query can be used on a `TRIGGER` to `UPDATE` the table after `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` of the `scores` table, automatically:

```
DELIMITER //

-- trigger on UPDATE of table scores.
CREATE TRIGGER upd_players AFTER UPDATE ON scores
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE `players` p SET p.high_score = (
            SELECT MAX(score) 
            FROM scores 
            WHERE id_player = p.id AND id_player = NEW.id_player
        );     
    END;//

-- trigger on INSERT of table scores.
CREATE TRIGGER ins_players AFTER INSERT ON scores
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE `players` p SET p.high_score = (
            SELECT MAX(score) 
            FROM scores 
            WHERE id_player = p.id AND id_player = NEW.id_player
        );     
    END;//   

-- trigger on DELETE of table scores.
CREATE TRIGGER del_players AFTER DELETE ON scores
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      UPDATE `players` p SET p.high_score = (
          SELECT MAX(score) 
          FROM scores 
          WHERE id_player = p.id AND id_player = OLD.id_player
      );     
    END;//  

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Isn't the group by redundant here in your first query?

Comment: Thank you very much guys. What simple and nice solution!
I was following the wrong way and problem was getting too complex ;-)